# ASP.NET Core: dotnet run does not work in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

When I try to run `dotnet run` (same for `watch`) in a Docker container, I cannot access my ASP.NET Core project.

This is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS restore
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["UI/UI.csproj", "UI/"]
COPY ["Core/Core.csproj", "Core/"]
RUN dotnet restore "UI/UI.csproj"
COPY . .

FROM restore AS development
WORKDIR "/src/UI"
CMD dotnet watch
```

This is my compose file:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    image: ithub-ui-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: UI/Dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

This is the output I get:

```
server-1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[15]
server-1  |       Overriding HTTP_PORTS '8080' and HTTPS_PORTS ''. Binding to values defined by URLS instead 'http://localhost:5142'.
server-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
server-1  |       Now listening on: http://localhost:5142
server-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
server-1  |       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
server-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
server-1  |       Hosting environment: Development
server-1  | info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
server-1  |       Content root path: /src/UI
```

I suspect it has something to do with the warning, but I can for the life of me not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: is having dotnet watch\run is necessary? Because as i see you just need to have your asp.net app in docker

Comment: Try to use `"8080:5142"`, instead of `8080:8080`, because it is listening on: http://localhost:5142.

Comment: @JasonPan, an obvious solution, but for some reason it does not fix the problem. I simply get a connection refused page

Comment: @RedStar, yes, `dotnet watch` is necessary since I want a development environment in docker

Comment: @CasperKoch, you can set it by giving value to ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Comment: @RedStar, what are you referring to? What should i set in the environment variables?